# macOS shell: JAVA_HOME is empty inside script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sh, java-home

I have macOS 10.11.6. The `JAVA_HOME` is set in the `.bash_profile` as

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

From command line, I can see it

```
>echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But, the `JAVA_HOME` is empty, when I run the following script

```
#!/bin/sh
SHELL=/bin/sh
export SHELL

echo $JAVA_HOME

if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    #do something
else
    echo JAVA_HOME is empty
fi
```

Even if I use `#!/bin/bash` in my script, the `JAVA_HOME` is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Depending on how you run your scripts, you may need to put your exports into *~/.bashrc* for interative shells, or directly into your script or crontab so that it doesn't rely on exports from your user's shell.

### Bash Startup Files

Simplistically, the *~/.bash_profile* script is sourced for login shells (e.g. `/bin/bash -l`), while the *~/.bashrc* file is sourced for interactive shell (e.g. `/bin/bash -i`). It's actually a bit more complicated than that, but the above should get you pointed in the right direction.

### See Also

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash
- https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash#INVOCATION
- `man 1 bash`

Answer (score 0):

I configure mine like this:

```
# configure Java  http://www.jenv.be/
# install Java: brew cask install java, brew cask install java7
# set global default: setJavaGlobal 1.7, jenv global 1.7
# set local folder default: jenv local 1.8
#
JENV_HOME=$HOME/.jenv
export PATH=.:$PATH:$JENV_HOME/bin
eval "$(jenv init -)"
export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/`jenv version-name`"
alias jenv_set_java_home='export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/`jenv version-name`"'
```

And some related shell methods I use in my .bash_profile :

```
setJavaGlobal() {
  jenv global $1;
  jenv_set_java_home
  echoJavaSetup
}
setJavaLocal() {
  jenv local $1;
  jenv_set_java_home
  echoJavaSetup
}
echoJavaSetup() {
  echo --------------------
  echo NEW JAVA SETUP:
  echo "  PATH: $PATH"
  export JAVA_VERSION=`java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version' | awk '{print $3}'`
  echo "  JAVA: $JAVA_VERSION, $JAVA_HOME"
  jenv versions
  echo --------------------
}
removeJavaLocal() {
  rm -rf ./.java-version
}
showJava() {
  echo --------------------
  echo EXISTING JAVA SETUP:
  echo "  PATH: $PATH"
  export JAVA_VERSION=`java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version' | awk '{print $3}'`
  echo "  JAVA: $JAVA_VERSION, $JAVA_HOME"
  jenv versions
  if [ -f ./.java-version ]; then
    echo "Using Java LOCAL DEFAULT.  Not using global default!  Run command 'removeJavaLocal' to change to global default."
  fi
  echo --------------------
}
```